# Which USB 2.0 chip to interface PC with FPGA?

Tags: usb, fpga

I'm planning to build a software defined radio.

I'm looking for some chip to get out data from FPGA, and sending it inside. I need to use parallel interface. I read about an FT4232, but these don't have really fast parallel modes. Or maybe I should approach it differently?

I need also to configure the FPGA using that interface, so I have to bitbang Spartan-6 pins.

Do you think I will be able to use CCLK and DIN pins after configuration in FPGA normal operation?

[image: FPGA configuration]

Can you advise me some chip to use?

Comment: "Shopping" questions are off topic.  You might spend some time looking at what existing SDR designs (eg for GNU radio etc) use in this role today.

Comment: I don't want to make use from ready to use product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FT2232H would probably be a good choice.  The FT2232H provides two interfaces, which are configurable for UART, FIFO, and JTAG, among others. So you can use one port in JTAG mode to configure the FPGA (using openocd) and another port in FIFO mode for reasonably high speed data transfer.  The FIFOs can run in async mode (8 MBps or 64 Mbps) or synchronous mode (40 MBps or 320 Mbps). How much bandwidth do you need?

Comment: USB 2.0 is too slow, the adalm pluto had this problem unfortunately.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing. OP didn't say anything about bandwidth requirements. If you do most of the processing on the FPGA, then you might not need all that much bandwidth. There are also compression techniques that can be used, such as sparsedr.

Comment: I need as big bandwidth as possible. 40MBps sounds nice. Using 14 bit ADC, and 22MSPS i get a speed requirements like 38,5MBs...

Comment: @alex.forencich oh the first thing i wanted to do is to interface that with gnuradio, i will make processing on fpga later