# FT2232HL - using FIFO to send continous data to processing + signaling information

Tags: fpga, ftdi, sdr

I'm designing a Software Defined Radio project.
I want to use an FPGA, DAC, ADC and FT2232HL bridge to handle communication with PC.
Can I stream continously data from PC to FIFO?
If I will use a FIFO mode of FT2232HL, and transmit RF samples continously(for DAC) through it, how can I handle transfer of "signaling data", something like turn ON Transmitter, turn on receiver, turn on standby? Can i use for this also same FIFO channel?

Thank You

Comment: Yes you can stream data continuously. If you can do it quickly enough is another matter. You other questions aren't very clear what you're after. What have you tried so far, what is your specific question?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I ordered an FT2232HL chips, and eval board with it. I'm using and FPGA with i will be connected using FIFO. And here is the question, how can I told an FPGA not to treat incoming data like a samples for DAC, but to interpret it, turn something on/off, or something another. @DaveTweed gave me an interesting idea which I started to consider seriously.

Comment: The FT2232 has two channels, see if you can use another in a lower performance mode for additional signaling.

Comment: second channel I consider to use for communication with an FPGAConfigurationLoader - https://github.com/ng91/FPGAConfigurationSubsystem

Comment: As with your previous question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522223/which-usb-2-0-chip-to-interface-pc-with-fpga you could learn a lot by studying existing open-source solutions.  You were insistent that you didn't want to "use an existing product" but studying something is not the same as using it. **If you're not willing to study other designs for the lessons they offer, then it's a bit illegitimate to be asking for open-ended recommendations.**  Either you do this project with available resources, or you do it in an isolation room by yourself.  Research before asking.

Comment: Please do not, for example, show up tomorrow or next week and repeate your unresearched FT2232 FPGA programming question with a question about how to configure and read the FT2232 FIFO from your PC, or build a quadrature NCO in an FPGA, **until you've actually reviewed some of the readily available *existing* solutions to such problems.**  When you've looked at how something is usually done, if there are aspects of that which are still puzzling, then those post-research questions are consistent with the mission of this site in a way that unreasearched questions are not.

Comment: I had tried to do it before. Often I don't understand what autor has on his mind. And what I have to do then? There is a bucketload of opensource code which is undocumented, and only author and people who code years know how it works. And that's why I ask there.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to approach this.

If you have only a small number of simple commands, then you can "reserve" some of the DAC data values for those commands. Obviously, this decreases the dynamic range of your signal very slightly.

A more general approach is to introduce a packet structure to the data. A header byte tells you what kind of packet you're sending — a short command packet or a long DAC data packet — and the FPGA does the right thing with each kind of packet.

Of course, you can do the same thing in the other direction, too.

Comment: Oh i wanted to avoid the first solution. Indeed it will decrease dynamic range.
I understand second approach, I was considering it, and You make I'm thinking about it more seriously. First 2 bytes maybe should I reserve for header. It's 16 bits, ~65536 types of headers are enough i think ;)
Thanks for response btw.

Comment: Which other way could You recommend me?

Comment: I used the second method on a project I did several years ago. I had a DSP chip connected to the FPGA, and there was also an FT245 (older version of the chip you're using) connecting the FPGA to the PC. There were also sensors of various types connected to the FPGA. So the packet structure was used on both of these links, allowing both the PC and the DSP to communicate with any of the sensors, as well as allowing them to communicate with each other.

Comment: While I believe the chip can support an out of band channel, assuming 16-bit data, if you reserve even 64 codes at the extreme of range, the chances of needing to use those for data and not *also* hitting the actual value limit problematically often are fairly low.  If the excursions are impulse noise, the filters won't really care if they get a slightly wrong value; if the excursions are added up signal power, you're misoperating your radio's gain settings and are already creating an intermodulation distorted mess causing false apparent signal copies to appear up and down the band anyway.